# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6/29/2006'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

My code is as follows:

First I create a zero matrix:

```
ww = (64,8)
tt14=np.zeros(ww)
```

This is a float matrix. When I want to assign a string value (Date) to the matrix, it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6/29/2006'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Numpy isn't going to like mixing datatypes inside an array

Comment: So, do you know how to get over this problem?

Comment: What float number do you want it to produce from `'6/29/2006'`?  `numpy` can handle dates, but the format is different, `numpy.datetime64('2006-06-29')`

Comment: It gives this error

Comment: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Answer (score 0):

The matrix expects Float types and the date is a type of String. You can convert the date to float by converting it into a timestamp first:

```
import time

date_str = "6/29/2006"
time_tuple = time.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y")
timestamp = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

Result `print timestamp`:

```
1151503200.0
```

On retrieval we can convert the timestamp back to string:

```
dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
date_str = dt_obj.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Result `print date_str`:

```
06/29/2006
```

### Or as pointed out in the comments

If the array is only used for string values you can pass a data type parameter to `numpy.zeros()` to populate the matrix with empty strings:

```
ww = (64,8)
tt14=np.zeros(ww, dtype = str)
```

Now you can add any string value to the matrix.

Comment: Or found that I need just to create a string matrix using      [[""] *8  for x in range(8)]

Comment: Yes! That would be best if you only plan to use the array for dates! This was not clear from the question so played it save. Updated my answer